# build gcc7.1 in wsl

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I get the following error after the make:

```
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kenbloom0303/build'
Makefile:26035: recipe for target 'stage1-bubble' failed
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kenbloom0303/build'
Makefile:941: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas where I should look for the error?

Comment: What were you trying to do?

Comment: make gcc 7.1 in native mode